# Replicate Image Block Hover Effect: Example Enclosed

Tags: css, hover, imageblocks

Here is the image block hover effect example:
[image]

Would someone please direct me in the right direction?  What is the CSS?

I'd like to replicate this hover effect on my image blocks.

Thank you for your help,

Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can play with `box-shadow`s a bit, too, to create a better illusion of depth as the card is hovered or focused. Other details:

- `Flexbox` wrapper around cards
- Grow cards using `transform`/`scale`
- `SVG` `transition` on `fill` property
- Added transparent border when card is not hovered or focused, to protect against text shift and jumpy behavior during hover/focus

[image]

```css
.cards {
  display: flex;
}

.card-image {
  max-width: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.card-image .svg-icon {
  transition: fill 0.3s cubic-bezier(.25, .8, .25, 1);
}

.card:hover .card-image,
.card:focus .card-image {
  fill: #97cb6f;
}

.card {
  font-family: helvetica;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(.25, .8, .25, 1);
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
}

.card:hover,
.card:focus {
  border: 2px solid #97cb6f;
  transform: scale(1.05, 1.05);
  box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
}

.card h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  font-size: 120%;
}

.card ul {
  padding: 0 0 0 1em;
}

.card li {
  margin-bottom: .5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="cards">
  <div class="card" tabindex="0">
    <div class="card-image">
      <svg class="svg-icon" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
       <path d="M17.896,12.706v-0.005v-0.003L15.855,2.507c-0.046-0.24-0.255-0.413-0.5-0.413H4.899c-0.24,0-0.447,0.166-0.498,0.4L2.106,12.696c-0.008,0.035-0.013,0.071-0.013,0.107v4.593c0,0.28,0.229,0.51,0.51,0.51h14.792c0.28,0,0.51-0.229,0.51-0.51v-4.593C17.906,12.77,17.904,12.737,17.896,12.706 M5.31,3.114h9.625l1.842,9.179h-4.481c-0.28,0-0.51,0.229-0.51,0.511c0,0.703-1.081,1.546-1.785,1.546c-0.704,0-1.785-0.843-1.785-1.546c0-0.281-0.229-0.511-0.51-0.511H3.239L5.31,3.114zM16.886,16.886H3.114v-3.572H7.25c0.235,1.021,1.658,2.032,2.75,2.032c1.092,0,2.515-1.012,2.749-2.032h4.137V16.886z"></path>
      </svg>
    </div>
    <h2>Some Title</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>Great</li>
      <li>Greater</li>
      <li>Greatest</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="card" tabindex="0">
    <div class="card-image">
      <svg class="svg-icon" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
       <path d="M17.896,12.706v-0.005v-0.003L15.855,2.507c-0.046-0.24-0.255-0.413-0.5-0.413H4.899c-0.24,0-0.447,0.166-0.498,0.4L2.106,12.696c-0.008,0.035-0.013,0.071-0.013,0.107v4.593c0,0.28,0.229,0.51,0.51,0.51h14.792c0.28,0,0.51-0.229,0.51-0.51v-4.593C17.906,12.77,17.904,12.737,17.896,12.706 M5.31,3.114h9.625l1.842,9.179h-4.481c-0.28,0-0.51,0.229-0.51,0.511c0,0.703-1.081,1.546-1.785,1.546c-0.704,0-1.785-0.843-1.785-1.546c0-0.281-0.229-0.511-0.51-0.511H3.239L5.31,3.114zM16.886,16.886H3.114v-3.572H7.25c0.235,1.021,1.658,2.032,2.75,2.032c1.092,0,2.515-1.012,2.749-2.032h4.137V16.886z"></path>
      </svg>
    </div>
    <h2>Some Title</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>Great</li>
      <li>Greater</li>
      <li>Greatest</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3dt2ujmL/)

Comment: @MikeAllen It probably warrants its own SO question, but [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ohgtm3wL/1/) it is. I added a `div` around the contents of the card (excluding the image) and `scale` only that new `div`.

Answer (score 1):

When the image gets hovered, you can scale it using `transform` property and add `border` to it. Below is a sample css code, replace it with your class name

```css
   .myimg {
      transition: all .4s ease-in;

    }

    .myimg:hover {
      transform: scale(1.1);
      border: 5x solid green;
      box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px #333;
    }
```

```html
<img src="https://www.dike.lib.ia.us/images/sample-1.jpg" class="myimg"/>
```

Comment: Worked perfect.  Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Welcome, if you got the answer you can mark any of the answers in this post as solved